# Firestore timestamp returning "Objects are not valid as react child {found: object with keys {seconds nanoseconds} an console

Tags: reactjs, firebase

When I try to retrieve Firestore `timestamp` (firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()) from a Firestore doc, an error occurs:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

And if I say `.seconds` it gives back lots of numbers and not a real date. What should I do?

Code Below

```
    const Comment = ({id, name, text, time}) => {
      const deletePost = () => {
        //dlete the image form firebase storage
        
        db.collection("posts").doc(id).delete()
        .then(function(){
          console.log("deleted POST")
        }).catch(function(error){
          console.log(error)
        });

      }
      return (
        <div style={{justifyContent: "space-around", maxWidth: "480px", marginTop: "10px", border: "2px solid #f3f3f3"}}className="comment">
          <div>
            <div>
          <strong>{`${text}`}</strong>
          <p>{`By ${name}`}</p>
          </div>
          
          </div>
          <h1>{time}</h1>// error here, even if i say time.seconds
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: Where are you assigning the value of the time prop?

Answer (score 2):

Firestore timestamp will return somethink like below.

```
nanoseconds: 0
seconds: 1578421800
```

> firebase. firestore. Timestamp A Timestamp represents a point in time
> independent of any time zone or calendar, represented as seconds and
> fractions of seconds at nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time.
>
> It is encoded using the Proleptic Gregorian Calendar which extends the
> Gregorian calendar backwards to year one. It is encoded assuming all
> minutes are 60 seconds long, i.e. leap seconds are "smeared" so that
> no leap second table is needed for interpretation. Range is from
> 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z to 9999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z.
>
> constructor new Timestamp ( seconds :  number ,  nanoseconds :  number
> ) : Timestamp Creates a new timestamp.
>
> Parameters seconds: number The number of seconds of UTC time since
> Unix epoch 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Must be from 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z to
> 9999-12-31T23:59:59Z inclusive.
>
> nanoseconds: number The non-negative fractions of a second at
> nanosecond resolution. Negative second values with fractions must
> still have non-negative nanoseconds values that count forward in time.
> Must be from 0 to 999,999,999 inclusive.

Ref:https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

So you need to convert it string format if you want to display it in reacjts

so you can do some think like this in  jsx

```
{new Date(time.toDate()).toDateString()}
```

Also you can format timestamp according to your needs

```
{new Date(time.toDate()).toDateString()}
{new Date(time.toDate()).toLocaleString()}
{new Date(time.toDate()).getDate()}
{new Date(time.toDate()).getDay()}
{new Date(time.toDate()).getMonth()}
{new Date(time.toDate()).getFullYear()}
```

Even simple solution is firestore has defult method withoud converting into new Date

```
{time.toDate().toDateString()}
{time.toDate().toLocaleString()}
{time.toDate().getDate()}
{time.toDate().getDay()}
{time.toDate().getMonth()}
{time.toDate().getFullYear()}
```

**toDate**

```
toDate ( ) : Date
```

> Convert a Timestamp to a JavaScript Date object. This conversion
> causes a loss of precision since Date objects only support millisecond
> precision.